# Lilypond: output to iPhone and iPad

Tags: lilypond

How can I generate pdf outputs that fit best on iPad and iPhone?

I could not find the right paper sizes in [Lilypond's predefined paper sizes](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/predefined-paper-sizes.html)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there is a public variable called `paper-alist` which contains all the recognized paper sizes, along with their dimensions. You can easily add your own paper type as per [the Lilypond docs about paper size](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/paper-size-and-automatic-scaling#setting-the-paper-size):

```
#(set! paper-alist (cons '("my size" . (cons (* 15 in) (* 3 in))) paper-alist))

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "my size")
}
```

(This adds a paper size called `my size` which is 15 inches wide and 3 inches high.) Besides the unit of `in`, you can also use `cm` and `mm`.